# Laravel eloquent how to display data from 2 table

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables, product and promotion. I do not know how I can display the price of both product and promotion(price after discount) based on product_id in blade. In blade i can only display price for promotion using {{$promotion->price}}

**Product Table**

id - name - price

**Promotion Table**

id product_id - price - discount

**Controller:**

```
 $latestProduct = Promotion::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->with('product')
    ->take(20)
    ->get();
```

**Model:**

1. Product Model

   ```
   public function promotion()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Promotion');
   }
   ```
2. Promotion Model

   ```
   public function product()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Product');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in blade file:

**Edit:**

```
@foreach($latestProduct as $product)
    {{$product->price}}
    {{$product->promotion->price}}
@endforeach
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll be better to make like this:

```
$latestProducts = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->with('promotion')
->take(20)
->get();
```

And, as mentioned Ali Özen, in your blade file you'll be able to iterate through your products and get product's promotion price with:

```
$product->promotion->price
```